# GCC - Adding Libraries

Tags: c, gcc

I want to use functions in the header files `gmp.h` and `mpfr.h`, which are in the file `/opt/local/include`.

But when I run `gcc` with `-v`, all of the search paths are something like `/Application/Xcode.app/Contents/etc`.

I have tried adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/include"` to `.bash_profile` but it doesn't work. The compiler either tells me that `'gmp.h' file not found`, or `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64`.

What should I do?

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not for include files.

Comment: Ok, what is the right way to do it then? Every page O visited seems to tell me a different thing. I also tried adding C_INCLUDE_PATH but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to add `-I/opt/local/include` to compile commands (to specify where the headers are) and `-L/opt/local/lib` and `-lgmp` and `-lmpfr` (possibly in the reverse order — MPFR before GMP) to link commands.

Comment: That works!!! Thank you so much. Would you mind explaining a little bit the logic behind this? For example if I had another header file header.h I need, how should I include it?

Comment: You include it with `#include "header.h"`.  You compile the code with `-I/directory/containing/header` to find the header.  You specify where the library (`libheader.a` or `libheader.dylib`, since you seem to be on macOS) is too, with `-L/directory/containing/lib` and `-lheader` — or whatever is appropriate.  The `-I` tells the preprocessor to look in the named directory for header files (so it looks for `/directory/containing/header/header.h`, for example).  The `-L` tells the linker where to find libraries (so it looks for `/directory/containing/lib/libheader.dylib` etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

You need to add `-I/opt/local/include` to compile commands (to specify where the headers are) and `-L/opt/local/lib` and `-lgmp` and `-lmpfr` (possibly in the reverse order — MPFR before GMP) to link commands.

> That works! Would you mind explaining a little bit the logic behind this? For example if I had another header file `header.h` I need, how should I include it?

You include it with `#include "header.h"`. You compile the code with `-I/directory/containing/header` to find the header.  You specify where the library (`libheader.a` or `libheader.dylib`, since you seem to be on macOS) is too, with `-L/directory/containing/lib` and `-lheader` — or whatever is appropriate.

- The `-I` tells the preprocessor to look in the named directory for header files, so it looks for `/directory/containing/header/header.h`, for example.
- The `-L` tells the linker where to find libraries (so it looks for `/directory/containing/lib/libheader.dylib` etc).
- The `-lheader` tells the linker to look for `libheader.a` or `libheader.dylib` (or local equivalents) for the libraries.

Except for the use of `.dylib` vs `.so` vs `.dll` vs … (and `.a` vs `.lib` vs …), the same principles apply to other systems too.

<sup>*This is probably a duplicate.*</sup>