# C++ : undefined reference to `mysql_init'

Tags: c++, mysql

I am trying to do mysql connection using c++, on Code::Blocks and mingw compiler on MSYS2.

Upon Compliling

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions  -c "D:\Programming Languages\03. Projects\cppdatabase\main.cpp" -o obj\Release\main.o
g++.exe  -o bin\Release\cppdatabase.exe obj\Release\main.o
```

I am getting this error

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `mysql_init'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5d): undefined reference to `mysql_real_connect'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My Code

```
#include<iostream>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    MYSQL* conn;
    conn = mysql_init(0);
    conn = mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "root", "", "db_test", 0, NULL, 0);

    if(conn)
    {

        cout <<" Connection to database successful:"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Connection unsuccessful"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have this installed :
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-libmariadbclient`

I tried different methods available online , none of them helped.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCC - Adding Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012010/gcc-adding-libraries)

Comment: This didnt solve the problem @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: You need to link against a library that supplies the missing symbols the error message references.